# Checkbox automatic disabled when checked in autopunching/ autocoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi can anybody has better idea than this one? Because this codes needs clicking the box to enable the disabled function. I want an automatic disabled if the box is already checked. Please help me i am just an amateur programmer not like you guys.. Thanks!

```js
$ = jQuery; 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("[type='checkbox']").on('change',function(){ 
    if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
      $("[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", true)
        .css("background","rgba(135, 206, 235, 0.4)"); 
    } 
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I was expecting a auto disable of those box that were not checked.

Comment: $ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("[type='checkbox']").on('change',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $("[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled",true).css("background","rgba(135, 206, 235, 0.4)");
      }
  });
});

Comment: Ok, but if you don't want the code to run because of a click, then when should it run?

Comment: My code will run if clicked. But I don't need clicking here because I have a autopunch code already it will automatically checked but the problem here is that this code will not disabled it needs to be clicked. This is a survey program by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple remove the `change` event callback so that the `if` statement executes as soon as the page is ready.

```js
$ = jQuery; 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if($("[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')) { 
      $("[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", true)
        .css("background","rgba(135, 206, 235, 0.4)"); 
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tried but not ended good..

Comment: @RobertJanSindo That's not super helpful. Did you get an error? What happened?

Comment: The checkbox didn't appear as disabled Scott..

Comment: My codes is working but is is needed to be click to activate the disabled function. All I need Scott is when the checkbox is already checked (by autopunching, no need to click) it will appear already as disabled those checkbox that were unchecked.

Comment: @RobertJanSindo yes, I understand what is happening (you've explained that several times). I've updated my answer after noticing a bug. Try again.

Comment: Thank you Scott for helping me on this

Comment: @RobertJanSindo You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote and mark as "the" answer.